# Fire a selected Index change event of a grid view on clicking any portion of a whole row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to Fire a selected Index change event of a grid view on clicking any portion of a whole row

It s like i dont want to show a select command rather than user can click any portion of a row means any column of a row and that row get selected

ANy help is appreciated

Comment: see http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view9FC28EE6-ACB0-4F51-BFE4-38B0B10134D5.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have provided the language, so i will show you an example in VB.NET(easy to convert to C#):

Handle the [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) event of the GridView in the following way:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            e.Row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
            e.Row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
            e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(DirectCast(sender,GridView), "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End Select
End Sub
```

The important line is:

```
e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(DirectCast(sender, GridView), "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
```

C#

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Comment: Another alternative is to have a hidden select button in a row and trigger the button click when row is clicked.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter What is the equivalent code for c#. SInce i dont know how to replace DirectCast

Comment: `e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)`